# python: set file path to only point to files with a specific ending

Tags: python

I am trying to run a program with requires pVCF files alone as inputs.  Due to the size of the data, I am unable to create a separate directory containing the particular files that I need.

The directory contains multiple files with 'vcf.gz.tbi' and 'vcf.gz' endings. Using the following code:

file_url = "file:///mnt/projects/samples/vcf_format/*.vcf.gz"

I tried to create a file path that only grabs the '.vcf.gz' files while excluding the '.vcf.gz.tbi' but I have been unsuccesful.

Comment: Does it need to be a url, as opposed to an ordinary local file path?

Comment: Im not sure if there is an alternative that I could use. I need a recursive object that feeds into this command

mt = hl.import_vcf(file_url, 
                   force_bgz=True, 
                   reference_genome="GRCh38", 
                   array_elements_required=False)

Comment: It's not a problem.  I was just surprised it needed to be a url.  If you have the file path, constructing a local url from it is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have, as written, is just assigning your file path to the variable `file_url`. For something like this, `glob` is popular but isn't the only option:

```
import glob, os

file_url = "file:///mnt/projects/samples/vcf_format/"

os.chdir(file_url)
for file in glob.glob("*.vcf.gz"):
    print(file)
```

Note that the file path doesn't contain the kind of file you want (in this case, a gzipped VCF), the `glob` for loop does that.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python) for more options.

It took some digging but it looks like you're trying to use the `import_vcf` function of [Hail](https://hail.is/docs/0.2/methods/impex.html). To put the files in a list so that it can be passed as input:

```
import glob, os

file_url = "file:///mnt/projects/samples/vcf_format/"


def get_vcf_list(path):
    vcf_list = []
    os.chdir(path)
    for file in glob.glob("*.vcf.gz"):
       vcf_list.append(path + "/" + file)
    return vcf_list


get_vcf_list(file_url)

# Now you pass 'get_vcf_list(file_url)' as your input instead of 'file_url'

mt = hl.import_vcf(get_vcf_list(file_url), force_bgz=True, reference_genome="GRCh38", array_elements_required=False)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your need is for this but you'd likely need to put these gzipped VCF files into a list and have your program take in a list of these VCFs as input.

Comment: instead of printing the file names, what command would be most appropriate to make the program list these vcf files as the input?

Comment: mt = hl.import_vcf(file_url,
                   force_bgz=True,
                   reference_genome="GRCh38",
                   array_elements_required=False)

Comment: Updated code to put the files in a list and pass that list as input.